# Best practice to remove sorting on 3rd click on DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I wanted my DataGridView to stop sorting when clicking a 3rd time on a column.
Currently I have subclassed it and overriden the ColumnheaderMouseClick like this :

```
private int _standardSortingIndex = -1;

protected override void OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(e);

    if (e.ColumnIndex == this.SortedColumn.Index)
    {
        if (this.SortOrder ==  System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == _standardSortingIndex)
            {
                // I use other code here when not binded, omitted here to keep the queston simple...
                ((BindingSource)this.DataSource).Sort = string.Empty;
                _standardSortingIndex = -1;
            }
            else
                _standardSortingIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but I ask myself is there no standard way to do this yet ? Do I still have to write code to get this very standard functionality or is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an event handler to the control's own ColumnHeaderMouseClick event, without any need for subclassing.

The reason this kind of behaviour doesn't come out of the box is simple: not all grids are filled using a data source.

Comment: but without subclassing i have to add the event to every datagridview

Comment: I have indeed a bindingsource here, but when not binded it is still possible, only needs other line of code to clear the filter.  It still is not simple why this is not out of the box behaviour, its not that difficult to do

Comment: Honestly, if this annoys you? Never, ever try Java Swing; it requires you to subclass for absolutely every little customization. Most programmers just build up their own toolsets over time. You have a little working thing here, now. Good for you; you can keep using it.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Subclassing does not annoys me. I use it alot because i do not want to write any code twice.  I was trying to explain that the subclassing is not the problem, the problem is that this functionality is still not out of the box while it is not so hard to make

Comment: My point was simply that barely _any_ functionality like that exists out of the box in Java Swing. I've had to subclass a tree view just to make it show icons on the tree nodes. Overall, don't expect functionality to already be in a framework. Just be happy when it does.